# How do you name i18n text?

Tags: internationalization

When I work on web application with my colleges. The name of i18n text are given quite freely.
It's like each one has his own rule of naming.

Take an example, we have a text "**Create a new item**", it is used for a link.

- A names the key in resources file like: **CreateANewItem**, which puts all word together.
- B prefers to name it like this: **CreateLinkText**, which describes it's usage in the application.
- C, however, wants to use: **CreateItemText**, which summarizes it's literal meaning.

When some text is longer or containing format of dynamic content. Naming varies a lot and agreement is hard to be met.

So I wonder whether there's a good naming rule or convention for the i18n text in different cases: short, long, with format, vulnerable to change, etc. Or how do you do this in your project? With this convention, maintenance can be easy and code is more readable.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd say whatever helps your translators understand what the item actually DOES. There are too many examples of literal translations that don't really make sense in the actual application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not something that I have seen so far in coding conventions. I guess it matters a lot less than other issues when it comes to coding standards.  That said, I don't know what platform you are using, but if it's .NET there is a very short page on naming conventions for resource identifiers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229037%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @clafou, I mean .NET and JavaScript resources. Although your link doesn't say much, it is helpful. Yes it doesn't quite matters, that's why I can't google a good answer or article talking about this. But since no one in our team is English speaker, and the naming are quite "random", I'd like to get advises before the resources go into a mess.